# therubyracer v8 init.so Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby, apache, v8, puma, therubyracer

I'm running Centos 6.5, apache2 and ruby 2.1.2p95 and trying to start Puma server for my sinatra app. It continues to fail giving an extremely long output but it appears the real error is:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/therubyracer-0.11.3/v8/init.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000007fc90
```

here's a bigger chunk of the output:

```
-bash-4.1$ bundle exec puma -e staging
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 2.9.1 (ruby 2.1.2-p95), codename: Team High Five
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: staging
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/therubyracer-0.11.3/v8/init.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000007fc90
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0042 p:-17562721875862 s:0153 e:000152 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0041 p:---- s:0151 e:000150 CFUNC  :require
c:0040 p:0023 s:0147 e:000146 TOP    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-0.11.3/lib/v8.rb:4 [FINISH]
c:0039 p:---- s:0145 e:000144 CFUNC  :require
c:0038 p:0009 s:0141 e:000140 METHOD /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:97 [FINISH]
c:0037 p:---- s:0138 e:000137 IFUNC
c:0036 p:---- s:0136 e:000135 IFUNC
```

I was using a newer version of therubyracer, but saw a post where someone suggested rolling back and that didn't work.

It also seems like this isn't always the error I'm getting. one time it was the sass gem that failed, but this was the most often

Comment: show your gemfile please.

Comment: It's problem to install NodeJS as ExecJS environment instead of therubyracer? I've got bad experiences with rubyracer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I did figure out how to get around this and it was a good fix for me b/c I plan on deploying Node.js projects anyhow, but as Jan Strnádek sad in the comment above, the whole issue could be avoided by installing node.js

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-run-a-node-js-app-on-centos-6-4-64bit

I then commented out therubyracer gem and any dependencies and `bundle install` again and the server started right up no problem.